# Is There a Way to Turn a Column of File Names Into Link to That File in a .mdb File in Access?

Tags: file, ms-access, directory, hyperlink, prepend

Is There a Way to Turn a Column of File Names Into Link to That File in a .mdb File in Access?

I have an Access file with a column of file names, for example:

```
Column Name
cat.pdf
dog.pdf
happy.pdf
candy.pdf
```

The access file is within a folder called "example"
There is a folder within example called "image"

All the pdfs referenced in the access file are in the image folder.

So

```
    .
    |--example
         |----image
         |      |---cat.pdf
         |      |---dog.pdf
         |      |---happy.pdf
         |      └---candy.pdf
         └----cdrom.mdb
```

I believed it would be as simple as prepending the entire column containing these file names with "image" but I could not find an efficient way to do that.
I know how I could manually hyperlink each file name, but I've got hundreds that need to be converted to working hyperlinks to their files within the "image" folder.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, a clickable hyperlink is composed of 3 parts separated by # character.

If you want a clickable link on a form, calculate in textbox ControlSource:

`="#" & CurrentProject.Path & "\image\" & [fieldname] & "#"`

Set textbox IsHyperlink property to Yes.

Link is clickable on report in ReportView, not PrintPreview. Exporting report to PDF should preserve clickable links in PDF.

If you want clickable hyperlink in table, table must have a field defined as  Hyperlink type. An UPDATE action SQL can populate that field.
`UPDATE table SET [hyperlink field name]="#" & CurrentProject.Path & "\Image\" & [filename field] & "#"`

For other image types (png, jpg, bmp), calculation without # characters can be used in an Image control to display on form or report.

Comment: I do not want to turn it into a form.

Comment: Then option is to update a Hyperlink type field in table with the calculated value.

Comment: If answer resolves issue, please mark accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The path to those file should be:

```
PdfPath = CurrentProject.Path & "\image\" & [Column Name]
```

Comment: I'm very new to Access, where would I type this?

Comment: That is VBA setting a variable. Then use the constructed path with FollowHyperlink function to open file.

Comment: I'm sorry... I still don't understand. How do I use that to set a variable, Or how to use a constructed path.. or FollowHyperlink function. I'm End User Computing support and this is for someone that works in logistics. I really don't know anything about Access.

Comment: Then you are being very generous with your time. In my experience, IT refused to assist with products not approved on 'supported' list. They installed Access but then we were on our own figuring out how to use. Zero assistance with learning and programming.

Comment: Ah gotcha.  Yes I do understand programming concepts. I just don't know how to navigate MS-Access. It's not very widely used here, only by one guy that does importation. I do not want to turn the .mdb into a form. I want to be able to directly click the cell within Access. I've never worked with macros, procedures, or done anything with Access. The .mdb files the user gets from UPS used to have hyperlinks that worked, they contacted UPS support about it and the person that worked on this stuff left UPS.

Comment: Then I expect to proceed, you will need to spend a week with an introductory tutorial to acquire basics. You do not 'turn the mdb into a form', you build a form within the mdb and write code behind it. So your options have been described, pick one: either modify table or build a form.